# trouble with my loop

Tags: exclude

I am trying to exclude categories from my blog page. I have the code all set up and according to the codex, this should work

```
 $string = '-' . implode( ',-', explode( ' ', $data['exclude_categories'] ) );
```

The above line will print this to the screen upon testing

-homepage,-recent-news

Those are the two test categories that I am trying to remove from the blog page. Then I start my query like so

```
 <?php query_posts($query_string .  '&cat=' . $string);?>
    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 
 my other code stuff here
```

when I test the blog page, all the posts show up. I can't figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cat` accepts category IDs, not slugs or names. a better method here is to use the [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action, the Codex page has [an example](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts#Example%3a_Exclude_categories_on_your_main_page) that does exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: that method doesn't work for me either. In the example, they are using ID's also. The function uses is_home(), my blog isn't on the homepage. I tried is_page but that gave me undefined index errors. I also tried category_name =- homepage but that gave me weird results. It cut out the wrong category

Comment: if your blog is assigned to a page under reading settings, then it is the home page, see [conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) for more info. you can't exclude using category names, you have to use IDs.

Comment: Ok, thanks Milo. I have used my method above in the past but I realized after your comments that the framework returned the ID instead of the category slug.

Comment: I have been been looking over my code above. So I am trying to get the category id by using the get_category_by_slug() but I am getting nothing when I echo out for a test. when I tried using a foreach loop, I got an invalid argument passed to implode $cat = explode( ', ', $data['exclude_categories'] ) ;
foreach ($cat as $categories){
 $string = get_category_by_slug( implode(',',$categories));
 echo $string;
}